# phpexcel - looping doesn't works correctly

Tags: phpexcel

I have a foreach in a foreach to get data parents in a column. It works good in PHP but not in PHP excel
See the screen shots:
This is what i want to get

[image]

But it fills only the datas from the second loop:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    $row=7;
    $column = 'A';

    $refcodegests = RefGest::find_by_sql('SELECT DISTINCT c.code, p.lib ..."');
    foreach ($refcodegests as $refcodegest) {

        $Code = $refcodegest->code;
        $Lib = $refcodegest->lib;

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $column . $row, $Code . ' -' . $Lib );
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('3F6E89');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

            $refcodeacts = RefGest::find_by_sql('SELECT DISTINCT c.code_action, a.lib_action...
                                                FROM cap_val_charges c,com_ref_action a
                                                    WHERE c.code_gestion="'.$CodeGestion.'" ...');

                foreach ($refcodeacts as $refcodeact) {                  
                    $CodeAction = $refcodeact->code_action;
                    $LibAction = $refcodeact->lib_action;
                                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $column . $row, $CodeAction . ' -' . $LibAction );
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('DFDFDF');
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('233748');
                                    $row++;
             }
            $row++;
        }
```

Anybody an idea what is to change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move your second `$row++` ***above*** your second `foreach()` loop:

```
$row=7;
$column = 'A';

$refcodegests = RefGest::find_by_sql('SELECT DISTINCT c.code, p.lib ..."');
foreach ($refcodegests as $refcodegest) {

    $Code = $refcodegest->code;
    $Lib = $refcodegest->lib;

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $column . $row, $Code . ' -' . $Lib );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('3F6E89');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

    $row++;

    $refcodeacts = RefGest::find_by_sql('SELECT DISTINCT c.code_action, a.lib_action...
                                           FROM cap_val_charges c,com_ref_action a
                                          WHERE c.code_gestion="'.$CodeGestion.'" ...');

    foreach ($refcodeacts as $refcodeact) {                  
        $CodeAction = $refcodeact->code_action;
        $LibAction = $refcodeact->lib_action;

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $column . $row, $CodeAction . ' -' . $LibAction );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('DFDFDF');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('233748');
        $row++;
    }
}
```

Otherwise your first `$refcodeact` is overwriting the `$refcodegest` that you've just set